# What is the highest performance way to work with results in a List<SOBject> returned from Database.query()?

Tags: dynamic-soql, database, dynamic-apex

I have a custom object called Query_Definition__c that has two fields:

- SObject_Name__c (text)
- SOQL_Query__c (long text)

Within Apex, the requirement is to take the record details from the Query_Definition__c object and use them in a Database.query() call in a dynamic context.

SObject_Name__c will *always* have the proper name of a SObject within the system (e.x. Account, Custom_Object__c, Case, etc.).

SOQL_Query__c will *always* have a String value that represents a properly formatted SOQL query.

```
// Sample Query_Definition__c record

Query_Definition__c qd = new Query_Definition__c(
  SObject_Name__c = 'Lead';
  SOQL_Query__c = 'SELECT Id, Company, Status FROM Lead';
);

insert qd;

// Get the Query Definition record back and access it's field values

List<Query_Definition__c> qdList = [SELECT Id, SOBject_Name__c, SOQL_Query__c FROM Query_Definition__c LIMIT 1];
```

After getting the Query_Definition__c record back, I use the details to call a Database.query() method:

```
String qdSoql = String.escapeSingleQuotes(qdList[0].SOQL_Query__c);

List<SObject> dynamicQueryResultList = Database.query(qdSoql);
```

I need to then be able to iterate over the records and their fields within dynamicQueryResultList and perform DML operations within.  **What is the highest performance way of handling this situation?**

This works but cannot access the fields in the result set:

```
// This works but cannot access field values in the rows
List<SObject> dynamicQueryResultList = Database.query(qdSoql);

for(integer i = 0; i <= dynamicQueryResultList.size(); i++) {
    System.debug(i);
}

// But this fails with an error code of, "Error: Variable does not exist: Company"
List<SObject> dynamicQueryResultList = Database.query(qdSoql);

for(integer i = 0; i <= dynamicQueryResultList.size(); i++) {
    System.debug(i.Company);
}
```

And even though I know the List contains only Lead records which would grant me access to the field values during iteration, this does not work for casting or list construction

```
SObjectType sObjType = ((Sobject) Type.forName(qdList[0].SOBject_Name__c).newInstance()).getSObjectType);
// above returns Lead successfully

// Returns error: Unexpected token '<'
List<sObjType> dynamicQueryResultList = Database.query(adSoql);
//
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, arrays in Apex are zero-indexed.

Use:

```
for(integer i = 0; i < dynamicQueryResultList.size(); i++) {
```

To avoid an index out of bounds exception.

Second, almost all methods have similar performance characteristics. Don't micro-optimize for performance.

Third, you can access a field dynamically via the get method:

```
System.debug(i.get(Lead.Company));
```

Or:

```
System.debug(i.get('Company'));
```

Forth, you can't dynamically cast to an unknown type. You can construct a list type dynamically, such as:

```
Type.forName('System','List<'+qdList[0].SOBject_Name__c+'>').newInstance();
```

But this won't help you with the last lines of code, because data types must be resolved as compile-time, not dynamically at runtime.

You most likely want to use the [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) documentation, read it carefully, it explains everything you need to know about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is on generic sobject and you are trying to access a field from Lead sobject, you need to access the field name in below manner:

```
list<sObject> dynamicQueryResultList = DataBase.query(qdSoql);
for(sObject sobj : dynamicQueryResultList)
{
   system.debug(sobj.get('Company')); //where Company is the field API name
}
```

sobject.get(fieldapiname) returns the data in object format. you need to typecast it to a field's datatype such as
String companyName = (String)sobj.get('Company');